# Equation of light beam through a dielectric block

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, dielectric

Suppose we have a light beam $E^{(in)}(x,y,z=0)$.

Using the the Fresnel-Huygens propagator, the light field travelling through air at any $z$ value from the transmitter is provided by:

$$E_r (x,y,z)=∫dξdηE_r (x-ξ,y-η ,0)  \exp{\left(\frac{iπ}{λz} (ξ^2+η^2)\right)}$$

What would the equation of light be if the light travels passes through a dielectric block (wall) and exits it. Is the equation of the light a distance $d$ away from the block the same as the one above.

Comment: Why are you interested in using the propagator? As mentioned by @Ipz in its current form it is somewhat limited in its utility. There are some subtle points about coherence of the light. If you assume you perfectly coherent, far from the dielectric you would still have the intensity modulated by the interference, if the block is thick compared to the coherence length, then you would have something similar to the equation but with a reduced amplitude due to the reflection losses. If you want to define a beam you might want to start with a complete gaussian or other beam then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small caveat, your propagator is valid only for monochromatic waves. Furthermore, you are using the paraxial approximation with optic axis is $z$. Btw you forgot the normalization factor, which is why your formula is not dimensionally correct. Check out for example Thorn and Blanford’s *Modern Classical Physics* (eq. 8.28).

You didn’t specify the setup, but I’ll assume the dielectric wall to be perpendicular to the optic axis. Up to translation, I’ll assume that it extends between the planes $z=\pm d/2$ with $d$ the thickness of the wall. In a similar fashion, I’m guessing you are looking for the propagator from the plane $z=z_i<-d_w/2$ to $z=z_f>d_w/2$ with $d_w$ the wall’s thickness. I’ll assume that the wall is made of a linear isotropic dielectric.

The propagation of the field can be decomposed into $5$ steps:

1. Going from $z=z_i$ to $z=-d/2$ through the air
2. Crossing the air-wall boundary from $z=-d/2^-$ to $z=-d/2^+$
3. Going from $z=-d/2$ to $z=-d/2$ through the wall
4. Crossing the wall-air boundary from $z=d/2^-$ to $z=d/2^+$
5. Going from $z=d/2$ to $z=z_f$ through the air

And you just need to convolve the corresponding propagators. Actually, steps $2.$ and $4.$ perfectly cancel, and you can regroup $1.$ and $5.$ to get an effective propagation of distance $d_a=z_f-z_i-d$ through the air. Finally, the propagation through the dielectric is the same as through the air, up to a change of wavelength $\lambda’$.

The total propagator is therefore a convolution of two Gaussians which is still Gaussian. The prefactor is simply the inverse of the sums of the inverse of the prefactors.

In the case of a lossless dielectric, then $\lambda’$ is real and can be written $\lambda’=\lambda/n$ with $n$ the relative refractive index of the wall with respect to the air. The propagator is then exactly the same as your formula, only you replace the real distance $D=d_a+d_w$ by an effective distance:
$$
\tilde D =d_a+\frac{d_w}{n}
$$

(Note that this is not the optical path length). However, since you are talking of a wall, the there probably is some opacity. The result however is unchanged, and you need only give $n$ an imaginary part and separate the imaginary Gaussian kernel (like you had) from the real one (like a heat kernel translating attenuation).

Hope this helps.