# What's the diffraction pattern for free-space propagation plus a thin lens at arbitrary distances?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction, lenses

I am trying to analytically solve the light propagation for the following case:

1. Starting complex field $E_0$
2. Fresnel ropagation for a distance $d$ to a lens
3. Lens applies phase modulation with focal length $f$
4. Propagation from lens to a target plane for a distance $z$.

All steps individually are clear to me.

I know (by considering e.g. Goodman, Introduction to Fourier optics) that *if* I know the field right before the lens $E_L^-$, I also know the field at a plane $z$:

$$E(x, y, z) = e^{i\frac{\pi}{\lambda z}(x^2 + y^2)} \mathcal{F}(E_L^- e^{i\frac{\pi}{\lambda}(1/z - 1/f)(x'^2 + y'^2)})|_{f_x = \frac{x}{\lambda z}}$$

For the case that $z = f$, the phase factor inside the FT vanishes and I would be left with

$$
E(x, y, z) = e^{i\frac{\pi}{\lambda z}(x^2 + y^2)} \mathcal{F}(E_L^-)|_{f_x = \frac{x}{\lambda z}}
$$

I could then (again following Goodman) relate $$\mathcal{F}(E_l^-)$$ to the input field $E_0$ by the Fresnel propagator in k-space, e.g.
$$\mathcal{F}(E_l^-) = \mathcal{F}(E_0) e^{ikd}e^{i\pi\lambda d(f_x^2 + f_y^2)}$$

But I don't know how to solve if $z \neq f$, i.e. if the exponential inside the FT doesn't vanish.

Can anyone recommend me some links or helpful calculations?
Thanks.

Edit:
Following the comment below, I can write the field at lens as a convolution of starting field and kernel:
$$E_l^-(x', y') = E_0 * h(x', y')$$ with

$$ h(x', y') = e^{\frac{ikd}{i\lambda d}} e^{\frac{ik}{2d}(x'^2 + y'^2)} $$

I don't how to continue from here, though.

Edit 2:
What I'm basically trying to achieve is to re-derive an expression from [this](https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-15-4-1913&id=127261) paper (equation 1), where the authors state that the light field for the setting above at coordinates $(x_m, y_m, z_m)$ is given by

$$
E(x_m, y_m, z_m) = \frac{\exp{(i2\pi(f + z_m) / \lambda )}}{i}\frac{d^2}{\lambda f} \int E_0(x', y') e^{-i\Delta^m(x', y')}
$$

where

$$
\Delta^m(x', y') = \frac{\pi z_m}{\lambda f^2}(x'^2 + y'^2) + \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda f}(x_mx' + y_m y')
$$

Comment: You can express the propagation in real space as a convolution by a gaussian (Fourier transform of a gaussian and Fourier transform of product). From there, you just need to calculate the resulting gaussian integral at the lens to get the final field.

Comment: @LPZ I am aware that I can write real-space propagation as a convolution. But then the expression gets even more difficult to handle, doesn't it? Could you maybe elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is essentially the same as in a previous answer of mine [Equation of light beam through a dielectric block](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742656/equation-of-light-beam-through-a-dielectric-block/743599#743599), only the interface is treated differently. There are some mistakes in your formula of the kernel (probably typos).

You have three steps, the formulas are taken from Thorn and Blanford’s *Modern Classical Physics* (eq. 8.28, eq. 8.29), using the notation of wavenumber $k=2\pi/\lambda$:

1. Propagation for a distance $d$ to the lens:
   $$
   E_1 = h_d*E_0 \\
   h_d = \frac{-ik}{2\pi d}e^{ikd}e^{\frac{ik}{2d}(x^2+y^2)}
   $$
2. Propagation through the lens:
   $$
   E_2 = l_f E_1\\
   l_f = e^{\frac{-ik}{2f}(x^2+y^2)}
   $$
3. Propagation through a distance $z$:
   $$
   E = h_z*E_2
   $$

Putting it all together:
$$
E(x,y) = \int dx'dy'\int dx_0dy_0 h_z(x-x',y-y')l_f(x',y')h_d(x'-x_0,y'-y_0)E_0(x_0,y_0)
$$
To find the relation between $E$ and $E_0$, you just need to integrate out $x',y'$. Thankfully, in this case, the integral is doable analytically, since it is a Gaussian integral.

Focusing on the $x',y'$ dependent terms:
$$
\begin{align}
H &:= \int dx'dy' \exp\left(\frac{ik}{2z}\big((x-x')^2+(y-y')^2\big)+\frac{-ik}{2f}(x'^2+y'^2)+\frac{ik}{2d}\big((x'-x_0)^2+(y'-y_0)^2\big)\right)\\
&=  \int dx'dy' \exp\left(\frac{ik}{2}\left[(z^{-1}-f^{-1}+d^{-1})(x'^2+y'^2)-2x'\left(\frac{x_0}{d}+\frac{x}{z}\right)-2y'\left(\frac{y_0}{d}+\frac{y}{z}\right)+\frac{x^2+y^2}{z}+\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2}{d}\right]\right)\\
&= \frac{2\pi}{ik(z^{-1}-f^{-1}+d^{-1})}e^{\frac{ik}{2}\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{z}+\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2}{d}\right)}\exp\left(-\frac{ik}{2(z^{-1}-f^{-1}+d^{-1})}\left[\left(\frac{x_0}{d}+\frac{x}{z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y_0}{d}+\frac{y}{z}\right)^2\right]\right)
\end{align}
$$

where I used the usual trick of completing the square and evaluating the gaussian integral.

You therefore get:
$$
\begin{align}
E(x,y) &= \frac{-k^2}{(2\pi)^2 dz}e^{ik(d+z)}\int dx_0dy_0 H(x,y,x_0,y_0)E_0(x_0,y_0) \\
&= \frac{ik}{2\pi (d+z-dz/f)}\int dx_0dy_0 e^{\frac{ik}{2}\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{z}+\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2}{d}\right)}\exp\left(-\frac{ik}{2(z^{-1}-f^{-1}+d^{-1})}\left[\left(\frac{x_0}{d}+\frac{x}{z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y_0}{d}+\frac{y}{z}\right)^2\right]\right)E_0(x_0,y_0)
\end{align}
$$

Hope this helps.